# IOException thrown by FXMLLoader.load(url) won't be catched

Tags: java, exception, javafx-8, fxmlloader

Im working on javaFX app and i want to run some code when the app crashes on startup so basically in the `start()` methode in the catch clause that surrounds the `FXMLLoader.load()` methode but for some reason it won't catch the `IOException` thrown by it.(I put a wrong url in the `getResource()` methode so that the exception is thrown)

But if i exchange `IOException` with the base class `Exception` it works, so is there a deeper nested `Exception` thrown before the `IOException` that i don't know about ? (the console displays a `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`)

**Update:**
I tried separating the `getResource()` and the `FXMLoader.load()` function and seperated them with a message to see where the `Exception` is thrown.
Conclusion : the `Exception` is 100% thrown by the `FXMLLoader.load()` methode.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    stage = primaryStage;

    try {
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("view/Lgin.fxml");
        System.out.println("URL loaded");
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
        System.out.println("FXML loaded");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(null));
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image("resources/icons/Login.png"));
        stage.setTitle("main");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        //LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
        //System.exit(0);
        System.out.println("catch reached");
    }
}
```

Stack trace :

```
URL loaded
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at launcher.DigitalCourt.start(DigitalCourt.java:42)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application launcher.DigitalCourt
Java Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception thrown is `NullPointerException` which is not a subclass of `IOException` that's the reason the exception is not caught.

`NullPointerException` is a `RuntimeException` so if you want to catch `NullPointerException` either catch `NullPointerException` or `RuntimeException`

The reason for the exception is caught when you use `Exception` because `RuntimeException` extends `Exception`.

To catch this particular exception you can do either

```
catch(IOException|NullPointerException e) {
    //LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
    //System.exit(0);
    System.out.println("catch reached");
}
```

or

```
catch(IOException|RuntimeException e) {
    //LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, e.toString(), e);
    //System.exit(0);
    System.out.println("catch reached");
}
```

Also `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` is not thrown from your code instead it is thrown from JavaFX which call your `public void start(Stage primaryStage)` since there is a exception JavaFX wraps the original exception inside `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`